# Scrapy saves array of images in json file too instead of only the url

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

After having learnt how to correctly download images with scrapy, I now am trying to produce a clean json file with only the images urls, but scrapy also saves an empty array of images about which I do not care at the moment.

```
def parse(self, response):
        raw_image_urls = response.xpath(".//img/@src").getall()
        clean_image_urls = []
        for img_url in raw_image_urls:
            clean_image_urls.append(response.urljoin(img_url))
        for clear_url in clean_image_urls:
            yield {
                'image_url': clear_url,  
            }
```

This produces:

```
{"image_url": "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/deep-forest-river-wild-waterfall-260nw-1585363855.jpg", "images": []},
```

Instead of just:

```
{"image_url": "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/deep-forest-river-wild-waterfall-260nw-1585363855.jpg"},
```

Which is what I need.

I modified the pipeline like this:

```
class customImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return request.url.split('/')[-1]
```

Which should just give me the image right name.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Does the solution you provided work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ImagesPipeline.item_completed`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.4.1/scrapy/pipelines/images.py#L165) sets that field, so you need to override it so that it does nothing:

```py
    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        return item
```